# How to launch the script that was Browserified from a browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I browserified a module that takes a value and returns a new one.

The original .js file was:

```
 module.exports = function (term) {
      return term + ' blabla';
 }
```

If I want to call it from Node.Js I'd simply include it as in

```
var foo = require('./my-file.js');
foo('no'); // returns 'no blabla'
```

But how do I call this same function from a browser if I include the browserify-generated file in `<script src="/javascripts/new-file.js"></script>`?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you compile with the -r flag?

Comment: I did `browserify my-file.js > new-file.js` as written in Browserify handbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `--standalone` flag for browserify. From the documentation:

> Generate a UMD bundle for the supplied export name. This bundle works with other module systems and sets the name given as a window global if no module system is found.

So if you use the `--standalone` flag,

```
browserify --standalone my_global_name my-file.js > new-file.js
```

you will be able to use the **window.my_global_name** property to access your function.

Comment: – ok i did that and then if i do `console.log(window.my_global_name)` it outputs the function, but how do I actually send it parameters and get it to provide the return? thanks!

Comment: ok, it worked, I did `window.my_global_name(parameter)` and it's fine. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile with the `-r` flag, to set it up as exposing for requiring.

```
browserify -r my-file.js > new-file.js
```

Then, in your script, you should be able to do:

```
var foo = require('./my-file.js');
foo('no'); // returns 'no blabla'
```

For more information, you can read [the documentation](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#external-requires).

Comment: When I try to do that, I get the following error:
`Error: Cannot find module 'node-stemmer.js' from '/Users/deemeetree/Documents/Root/InfraNodus/lib/sandbox'
    at module.exports.cb (/Users/deemeetree/.node/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:50:17)`